# Office.js displayDialogAsync throws internal error

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to display a dialog from an Outlook JS plugin running in Office 365's version of Outlook 2016 (recently updated, EXE version 16.0.8431.2107).

The code I enter in the F12 debugger console is as follows:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    window.location.origin,
    {width: 500, height: 500},
    function(result) { 
        console.log(result) 
    }
);
```

The result returned is

```
error:{
    code: 5001,
    message: "Ein interner Fehler ist aufgetreten.",
    name: "Interner Fehler"
},
status: "failed",
value: undefined
```

and no dialog is opened.

Am I overlooking some odd requirements there?

Comment: Are you running the add-in in OWA or Windows Outlook client?

Comment: @grg In Windows Outlook 2016 client, EXE version 16.0.8431.2107.

Comment: Try setting width and height values to less than 100 as these are percentages of the parent window that the dialog should occupy.

Comment: @Alexander The F12 debugger console is usually for a web browser. Just to clarify, are you saying that you launched the F12 debugger console in a web browser or in the Desktop Outlook client? Do you have a screenshot that you can share?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT C:\Windows\System32\F12\F12Chooser.exe can attach to Desktop Outlook client javascript add-ons

Comment: @Alexander, thanks for pointing out that you are using the F12Chooser. I just ran your code on a more recent version of Outlook using the F12Chooser and I'm able to see the dialog show up. Are you seeing this failure if you add this code to the app and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is fixed.

I said

> recently updated

and forgot to mention that I didn't reboot between update and my test (Office didn't tell me to). It seems that a reboot did the trick; I am now getting a dialog window.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to F12 debugging your script, could you verify the output of window.location.origin.

Office Add-in is based on IE and using a special security setting. IE might disable window.location.origin in that case.

On my own machine, I can see it returns 'undefined', so in that case you are passing undefined as url, and the API fails.

If you have latest IE installed, make sure in your html page, it has the following meta tag. It will force Office Add-in to use latest IE setting, instead of compatible view mode.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```